# Could an ECMA-262-conformant JavaScript implementation have `2n` be the maximum BigInt size?

Tags: javascript, bigint

As far as I can tell, the ECMASCRIPT spec doesn't say what the minimum maximum size for a BigInt value is, it just says ["arbitrary precision"](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-bigint-value), which seems in this context to mean ["implementation-defined"](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/174#issuecomment-437314908).

Does this mean that a JS engine could throw a `RangeError` on `BigInt(3)` and still conform to the spec?

Comment: https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-bigint-type *The BigInt type represents an integer value. The value may be any size and is not limited to a particular bit-width.* I suppose so

Comment: I think that being concerned that an implementation would actually restrict BigInt values to a small integer maximum is wildly unrealistic.

Comment: Why would an implementor bother with a BigInt implementation that would only serve to crash any program that attempts to use it? They just wouldn't support it all. There are probably a great deal of underspecified parts of the standard an evil implementor could exploit for laughs.

Comment: I think arbitrary precision means as much as the memory allows https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this would be a conforming (albeit silly) implementation. In a discussion on the BigInt proposal [it was mentioned](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/174#issuecomment-437314908) that

> *[The maximally allowed BigInt] is not specified. Implementations can choose their own limits. This matches other things in JavaScript, like the size of the stack, or max length of TypedArrays, which are also implementation-defined.*

There's also [an open ecma262 issue](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/1391) that ponders whether to "*define minimum or maximum guaranteed sizes for various resources*", but nothing came out of this yet.

Comment: Similarly, I believe an implementation where the maximum string length was two characters would also be spec compliant (but obviously rather useless for practical purposes).

Comment: What a sad story for cross-platform development!

Comment: @MaxHeiber Cross-platform development still means you will choose which platforms to support, and they'll have large enough bigintegers. Tbh I don't see why you would care