# How does BigInt.toString() work with very big BigInt?

Tags: javascript, biginteger, bigint

As it specified in the [`BigInt` spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-bigint-type):

> The value may be any size and is not limited to a particular bit-width

As it specified in the [`String` spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type):

> The String type is the set of all ordered sequences of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integer values ("elements") up to a maximum length of `2^53 - 1` elements

As it specified in the [`BigInt.toString` spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-numeric-types-bigint-tostring) 2nd point:

> Return the String value consisting of the representation of `x` using radix

[MDN says that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#description):

> However, a string with this length (`2^53 - 1` elements) needs `16384TiB` of storage, which cannot fit in any reasonable device's memory, so implementations tend to lower the threshold, which allows the string's length to be conveniently stored in a 32-bit integer

So imagine that I have enough memory/time/cpu and so on. What will I get when run `BigInt.toString()` if the `BigInt` is too large and it takes more than `2^53 - 1` elements to return the String value?

Comment: Make one and find out? I think this is just saying "`BigInt` can theoretically hold more than your computer can", or even more so it may not fit in a theoretically huge string. This is more of an academic concern than a practical one, unless you have a machine with 16PB of memory.

Comment: Given that it seems to be unspecified, it is likely implementation-dependent. And moot, given that the maximum memory I think current popular OSs can support is 128TB.

Comment: closely related: [How can an ECMA-262-conformant JavaScript implementation limit the maximum BigInt size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74971364/1048572)

Comment: "*What will I get?*" - uh, an exception?

Comment: @Bergi Do I understand correctly that the answer to the question is - it depends on the implementation? I mean that for example in FF I can get an `Error` but in Chrome I can get the string with the length of `2^53 - 1` elements without any errors?

Comment: For `2n ** (2n ** 30n)`, in FF: `Uncaught RangeError: BigInt is too large to allocate`. Chrome: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum BigInt size exceeded`.
In comparison, `2n ** (2n ** 29n)` is ok, but when I tried using `console.log`... it took so much time and memory, I just closed the browser before it could finish.

Comment: @EzioMercer Yes, it depends on the implementation (and possibly on the context, such as available memory). Though of course for bigints that would serialise to 2**53 digits or more, you'd get an exception in all implementations :-)

Comment: @qrsngky I gave a bad example, sorry :) I'm aware of bugs in browsers, I'm wondering what MUST happen according to the spec

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587490/how-does-bigint-tostring-work-with-very-big-bigint#comment133356913_75587490) @EzioMercer The spec that you linked to says "2. Return the String value consisting of the representation of _x_ using radix _radix_." It does not define specifics for this representation — therefore it is the responsibility of the implementation to interpret and define any unclear behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V8 developer here (who, among other things, implemented BigInts).

> What will I get when run BigInt.toString() if the BigInt is too large...

A `RangeError`. (Or, potentially, an OOM crash, depending on the implementation details of your JS engine.)

As of today, V8 (and hence Chrome, Node, Opera, Edge, ...) limits BigInts to `2**30` bits (and we have no plans to raise that; in fact we think this limit is already higher than it needs to be). AFAIK Firefox limits them to `2**20` bits (which seems to be more than enough for practical purposes). Trying to create bigger BigInts than that produces a `RangeError`.

Strings also have a maximum length in implementations, which is lower than the theoretical limit in the spec. In V8, depending on version/configuration/platform, the maximum string length is either `2**28` or `2**29` or `2**30`. Trying to create longer strings than that (by converting a BigInt, or by any other means) produces a `RangeError`.

> ...and it takes more than `2^53 - 1` elements to return the String value?

As commenters have pointed out, this part of the question is indeed an entirely theoretical question for the foreseeable future. Before the `2**53 - 1` theoretical string length limit can become a practical limit, we'll need an entirely new generation of computer architecture definitions.

Current "64-bit" software architectures (x86_64, aarch64) are actually limited to 48-bit virtual memory addresses. They can't address more than `2**48` bytes (256 TB) of memory (from an application's perspective), and they reserve half of that address space for the kernel.
Current (consumer-grade) hardware is typically limited to anywhere between about 35 and 48 bits for physical addresses.
So even if you could buy an actual machine with 256 TB of memory, and you found (or implemented) a JS engine with sufficiently high internal limits, and you filled your entire memory with a single BigInt, then that BigInt's base-2 string representation would still have a length of "only" `2**50` -- but of course, you wouldn't be able to allocate that string, because all your memory is already occupied by that BigInt; and even if (for the sake of argument) you networked a second machine with just as much memory just to hold the string, then you could only store `2**47` string characters in `2**47` bytes of non-kernel application memory (assuming your JS engine has a one-byte string optimization), and above that you'd either get a `RangeError` or an OOM crash depending on the implementation details of your engine.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! Of course my question is entirely theoretical question :) It just became interesting what should be according to the specification in such extreme cases. It was clear for me that if I create a string length of `2^53` or more I will get an `Error` because we have limit of length of `String` which is specified. But it is interesting for me why we don't have a limit for `BigInt`? Before I read the specification I thought that the limit of `BigInt` is `[-2^(2^52 - 1), 2^(2^53 - 1)]` because the longest representation of `BigInt` is the bit representation

Comment: For negative `BigInt` I wrote `2^52` because 1 element in string will be `-` as it specified in specification. So when I saw that `BigInt` doesn't have any limits I wondered how does `toString()` works then? I also read in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#instance_methods) that `BigInt.prototype.toString()` overrides the `Object.prototype.toString()` method so I thought that may be `BigInt.toString()` has its own implementation which gives for example two `Strings` in that case but didn't find anything

Comment: But now it clear that it depends on implementation of JS :)

Comment: "*all your memory is already occupied by that BigInt*" - LOL. +1!

Comment: @EzioMercer The reason Strings have a maximum length in the spec is that Strings have a `length` property, which returns a `Number`, which only has integer accuracy until `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, hence that's the maximum length a String is allowed to have. BigInts have no length, so there's no similar reason why the spec would have to define a limit for them.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in theory I can have `BigInts` of any size (much larger than `2^53 - 1` digits), I simply cannot convert them to `String`, but I can still work with them (e.g. sum them) ?

Comment: @EzioMercer "In theory" / per spec, yes. The JS spec imposes no limit on BigInt size at all, so per spec, you could "in theory" work with BigInts that need more memory than humanity has ever produced in all its factories combined. This is not unusual: the spec also allows recursion to arbitrary depths; it generally implicitly assumes implementation-defined limits on things like BigInt size, array/ArrayBuffer size, String length, recursion depth, etc.

Comment: @jmrk Thank you very much! I'm very grateful to you for detailed answers to all my questions!